# What is the correct way to implement Internationalization in your software?

Tags: django, flutter, software-design

- I'm doing a project in which have an Api in Django and to consume
  that Api I use flutter.  I want to implement an Internationalization,
  but I see that for both flutter and Django there are ways to
  Internationalize, Which one is a good practice?

Comment: Internationalization in Django is more for rendered templates and admin pages. So you should do it in flutter and translate static words and phrases inside the app.

Comment: You should store i18n static texts of your flutter apps in flutter. And in the case of dynamic content coming from django just pass the views a lang parameter like `api.com/lizards?lang=es`. And make the endpoints that need i18n handle it.